# Spark : Is there an equivalent to spark SQL's LATERAL VIEW in the Spark API?

Tags: apache-spark, lateral-join, sparkapi

Title says it all:

Is there an equivalent to the SPARK SQL `LATERAL VIEW` command in the Spark API so that I can generate a column from a UDF that contains a struct of multiple columns worth of data, and then laterally spread the columns in the struct into the parent dataFrame as individual columns?

Something equivalent to `df.select(expr("LATERAL VIEW udf(col1,col2...coln)"))`

Comment: `df.select("*", explode(udf(col1,col2...coln)))`?

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I actually solved this by selecting them by their tuple handles... see my answer below...

Comment: I think explode only blows out ARRAYS, not struct of a single set of values... I might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by selecting the udf into a column:

`val dfWithUdfResolved = dataFrame.select(calledUdf()).as("tuple_column"))`

... then ...

```
dfWithUdfResolved
  .withColumn("newCol1", $"tuple_column._1")
  .withColumn("newCol2", $"tuple_column._2")
  // ...
  .withColumn("newColn", $"tuple_column._n")
```

Basically using tuple notation to pull values out of the column into new discrete columns.